# MySQL recursive queries up on VARCHAR fields

Tags: mysql, select, varchar, recursive-query

I have a relation in MySQL which includes Geo-spatial data, which includes some bus halting places along a road. I understand that the approach to handle this in a RDBMS is to go with having two fields <halt_id> and <halt_next> where both are VARCHAR and the <halt_next> is the <halt_id> of next bus halt. What I want is to have a recursive query upon this relation to select one path. What shall I do?

Comment: please provide sample data in a fiddle and your desired out put

Comment: Here's the fiddle.[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e9aac)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would actually recommend having fields `halt_id` and `halt_prev`. The reason for this is that to find the first bus halt in a route, you have to find one with no previous halt (i.e. `halt_prev is null`).

```
select s1.halt_id, s2.halt_id, s3.halt_id
from Halt h1
left join Halt h2 on h2.halt_prev = h1.halt_id
left join Halt h3 on h3.halt_prev = h2.halt_id
where h1.prev_halt is null
```

This assumes that the routes aren't circular; if they are, it would be best to also use a `route_id` field and limiting it to one record per `route_id` as follows:

```
select o.route_id, i.halt1_id, i.halt2_id, i.halt3_id, i.halt4_id
from (select route_id, MIN(halt_id) halt_id_min
      from Halt
      group by route_id) o
join (select h1.route_id, h1.halt_id halt1_id, h2.halt_id halt2_id, h3.halt_id halt3_id, h4.halt_id halt4_id
      from Halt h1
      left join Halt h2 on h2.halt_prev = h1.halt_id
      left join Halt h3 on h3.halt_prev = h2.halt_id
      left join Halt h4 on h4.halt_prev = h3.halt_id
      where h2.halt_id not in (h1.halt_id)
      and h3.halt_id not in (h1.halt_id, h2.halt_id)
      and h4.halt_id not in (h1.halt_id, h2.halt_id, h3.halt_id)) i on i.route_id = o.route_id and i.halt1_id = halt_id_min
```

In both queries, the number of `left join`s and columns in the `select` statement (and, in the case of circular routes, the number of conditions in the `where` clause, minus 1) should equal the number of bus halts in the longest route (or the number of unique halts in a route, in the case of a circular route).

Comment: Thank you! Even though this is not the exact solution, this gives me a path to start research. Thank you so much.. I will keep this question updated with the result.. Thumbs up @Sander!